# cypress iframe function works on chrome but not firefox

Tags: firefox, cypress

I'm trying to run a test that involves iframes with firefox.  The test works with chrome but not with firefox.  It seems that when I get the iframe and subsequently try to find the body the body is returned as undefined.

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it.

cy.get('iframe').then(($iframe) => {
     const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body');
     cy.wrap($body)
        ^
```

The html looks the same for firefox as it does for chrome. Does anyone know what the underlying issue is for that?

Comment: This seems like a serious issue, may be contact cypress support on this email  

support@cypress.io

Answer (score 5):

The most likely cause is the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

In a nutshell, if the page loaded inside the iframe comes from a different domain than the parent page, then your javascript will not be allowed to access the DOM within the iframe.

The reason it is working for you on Chrome is likely because you have used this setting in your `cypress.json` config file to disable the same origin policy in Chrome:

```
   "chromeWebSecurity": false
```

As of this writing (Nov 2020), Firefox sadly does not have an equivalent way to disable the same origin policy for testing purposes.  The bug report is [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1039678).